# remove \n at beginning of row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read csv-files into pandas Dataframes with multiindex. Now I get a newline operator in the first index of each row and I cannot figure out how to set the `pandas.read_csv` function such that it is dropped. Since I use multiindex I have trouble changing the index after reading.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', lineterminator='\r', header= [0, 1], index_col = [0, 1]).astype(float)
```

what I get is what I expect the `\n` in the first index of each line.

```
             BG                CY
             grains vegetables grains vegetables
\n"AT" rice  0.0    0.0        2.34   0.54    
       wheat 0.0    6.04       0.0    2.43
\n"BE" rice  0.0    0.0        1.34   0.0
       wheat 8.7    1.9        0.45   0.0
```

Instead of `'\n"AT"'` I would like to have `'AT'`
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

change `lineterminator='\r'` to `lineterminator='\r\n'`

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error: ´Only length-1 line terminators supported´

Comment: How about lineterminator='\n'

Comment: This does work better because all indices are correct now, but it gives me a. `\r` at the end of the last column index.

Answer (score 0):

you could try :

```py
idx = df.index.levels[0].str.extract('([A-Za-z0-9]+)')
df.index = df.index.set_levels(idx.values.ravel(), level = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it into `io.StringIO` first

```
import pandas as pd
import io

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    file = io.StringIO(f.read())

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t")
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513311/15781748