# Read csv files with newline characters between columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have read and parse csv files using `pandas`, columns separated by semicolon `;`. Some of the files have (for unknown reasons) a `'\r\n'` sequence after some columns, which makes `pandas.read_csv` split them in different rows. I want to escape those characters and append the "second row" to the "first" one, otherwise the parsing gets difficult afterwards.

I could identify those lines, because they are followed by numbers, while the correct first column contains the time like `00:00:00`. Is it possible to do that with `pandas.read_csv`?

---

**Example**

With a correct file my code would look like this:

```
data = io.StringIO( ''' a; b; c; d 
                    x10; 20; 30; 40
                    x11; 21; 31; 41
                    x12; 22; 32; 42
                    x13; 23; 33; 43
                    x14; 24; 34; 44
                    x15; 25; 35; 45
                 ''' )

pd.read_csv( data, sep=';' )
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   10  20  30  40
1   11  21  31  41
2   12  22  32  42
3   13  23  33  43
4   14  24  34  44
5   15  25  35  45
```

**Problem**

With a damaged file, it looks like this:

```
data = io.StringIO( ''' a; b; c; d 
                        x10; 20; 30; 40
                        x11; 21; 31; 41
                        x12; 22; 
                        32; 42
                        x13; 23; 33; 43
                        x14; 24; 34; 44
                        x15; 25; 35; 45
                     ''' )

pd.read_csv( data, sep=';' )
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   x10     20  30  40.0
1   x11     21  31  41.0
2   x12     22      NaN
3   32  42  NaN     NaN
4   x13     23  33  43.0
5   x14     24  34  44.0
6   x15     25  35  45.0
```

The expected output, however, is the first one in both cases. In this example, I would think to replace `\r\n\d\d` by `\d\d` to get rid of those newline chars before/while constructing the dataframe in pandas.

If possible, I would like to avoid fixing the files first, avoid to make an extra script to just check all of them before reading with pandas, because there are new files coming regularly.

---

Is it possible to replace part of a string when reading csv files in pandas?

Is there another approach to this kind of problem?

---

Using python 3.6.8 , pandas 0.24.2

Answer (score 1):

That's something that happens commonly with big csvs. The way I would use to solve it would be to read them using python and check that the number of separators matches what you expect, otherwise remove the row. Then once the raw data is corrected you can load it in pandas using `StringIO`. An example over your wrong example:

```
# We load the file
filestream = open(filepath)

# Now we filter the data as follows
data = filter(lambda l: l.count(";")==3, filestream)

# Now we convert to String IO
stream = io.StringIO("\n".join(data))

# And finally we read with Pandas
pd.read_csv(stream, sep=';' )
```

Comment: Hi! I would like to keep the broken lines, so I changed the `filter` to search for regular expressions that I expect to be in the file. I will post my own answer below for reference. In any case, you pointed me in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the message. Yes, this is a general example that you can tweak :)

Answer (score 0):

I got parts from [ivallesp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513311/776515) and came up with a solution that keeps the broken lines.

I post it here as documentation for the future me (who often forgets such things) and also for others that might come across similar problems.

---

**Bad file, with broken lines**

```
infile = io.StringIO( ''' a; b; c; d 
                        x10; 20; 30; 40
                        x11; 21; 31; 41
                        x12; 22; 
                        32; 42
                        x13; 23; 33; 43
                        x14; 24; 34; 44
                        x15; 25; 35; 45
                     ''' )

# The lines are joined with a \n, and whitespace stripped
data = '\n'.join( [ item.strip() for item in infile ] )
# Now data is not a file stream, but a string, with \n s in between

#Search for occurrences of newline + NOT(x + number) and just keep
# found group 
data = re.sub( '\n(?!x\d\d)', '\1', data )

# Now data is a file stream again
data = io.StringIO( data )

# Fed to pandas.read_csv
pd.read_csv( data, sep=';' )
```

---

**Variation**

With an actual file in disk (not `io.StringIO`) I had to make a small modification, delete the `.strip()`, not sure why. Other than that, it works also joining on nothing (`''.join(...)`).

Lastly, my actual file has time in the first column, in the form of `00:00`, `00:05` and so on. So I actually used it like this:

```
import re

with open( 'broken_rows_file.csv', 'r' ) as infile:
    data = ''.join( [ item for item in infile ] )

#All that is NOT ##:## should be replaced
data = re.sub( '\n(?!\d\d:\d\d)', '\1', data ) 
data = io.StringIO( data )

df = pd.read_csv( data, sep=';' )
df

       a    b   c   d
0   00:10   20  30  40
1   00:11   21  31  41
2   00:12   22  32  42
3   00:13   23  33  43
4   00:14   24  34  44
5   00:15   25  35  45
```